# JMeter OS process sampler WinIOError

Tags: jmeter

I am using OS process sampler in JMeter to run a exe developed in.NET. I am getting below error:

The handle is invalid.

at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
at System.Console.GetBufferInfo(Boolean throwOnNoConsole, Boolean& succeeded) at System.Console.GetBufferInfo() at Sytem.Console.Clear() at MyApplication.Program.Main(String[] args)

How can I fix it?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to run the program using [cmd.exe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe) or [powershell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerShell) interpreter - you should be able to run the program using the [OS Process sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler), configure it like:

[image]

If your .NET application depends on some [.dlls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic-link_library) you might also need to set `Working Directory` for the process.

Check out [How to Run External Commands and Programs Locally and Remotely from JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter) article for more information if needed.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri. It is a desktop application like a console or a command prompt screen where I will enter inputs (numbers) to do some operations. The step you mentioned is not working. Can you suggest a solution?